Concat SQL Oracle Column into a string
I have a table below and would like to convert into below result into a string
table_name: employee_tb

    employee_id             employee_type
         1                        A
         2                        A
         3                        B
         4                        C
         5                        C
         6                        C

This is what I have so far
select employee_type, count(*) as employee_type_count
from employee_tb
GROUP BY employee_type;  

The result I got is:
 employee_type        employee_type_count
      A                       2
      B                       1
      C                       3

I would like to convert to below result. Is it possible?
result: A: 2, B: 1 C: 3

Thanks

Just put it in a subquery and use LISTAGG? https://dbfiddle.uk/XHfFpKkt

You can use LISTAGG here to concatenate the employee_type and employee_type_count:
SELECT LISTAGG(employee_type || ': ' || employee_type_count, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY employee_type) AS result
FROM (
    SELECT employee_type, COUNT(*) AS employee_type_count
    FROM employee_tb
    GROUP BY employee_type
) subquery;

Here is workplace with my query using LISTAGG db query

LISTAGG accepts COUNT function within it, so, with sample data:
SQL> with employee_tb (employee_id, employee_type) as
  2    (select 1, 'A' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'A' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'B' from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'C' from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'C' from dual union all
  7     select 6, 'C' from dual
  8    )

Query:
  9  select listagg(employee_type ||': '|| count(*), ', ') within group (order by employee_type) result
 10  from employee_tb
 11  group by employee_type;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A: 2, B: 1, C: 3

SQL>

If your database version supports it, you can even omit the within group part so it becomes just
select listagg(employee_type ||': '|| count(*), ', ')
from employee_tb
group by employee_type;

